# Changing css from jquery-ui.css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the background-color of my search results when I hover over them with my mouse. I use this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.16/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

When I go to `http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.16/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css` I found that

```
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
border: 1px solid #000000;
background: #1c1c1c url(images/ui-bg_glass_55_1c1c1c_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
font-weight: normal;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Handles the hover action, When I go to my css file and put in

```
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus { border: 1px solid #000000;
background: red;
font-weight: bold;
color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Nothing changes, any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how you add your css file to html this make sense but maybe just this can fix problem.

`background: red !important;`